# MergeSort -Recursively

Tags: java, recursion, merge, mergesort

How would you write this without the help of any packages ?
(same layout where mergeSort(int[] A) (take input of one array) and same with merge(int[] a, int[] l, int[] r)).
Main issue is  transalting Arrays.copyOfRange into the non -package version of java into this code.
Thank you for answering this question.

Another question of mine would be of how to implelment a merge function with 3 arrays this time in its parameters.

this is code i tried:

````
 public static int[] mergeArrays3(int[] a, int[] b, int[] c) {
        
       
        int[] result = new int[a.length + b.length +c.length];

        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, l=0;
        while(i<a.length &&j<b.length && l<c.length)

        {
//            if (b[i] < a[j] || b[i] <c[i]) {
//                result[k] = c[i];
//                j++;
//            }
            if (c[i] < b[j] || c[i] <a[i]) {
                    result[k] = c[i];
                    l++;
                }

            if (a[i] < b[j] || a[i] <c[i]) {
                result[k] = a[i];
                i++;
            }
            else {
                result[k] = b[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }
        while(i<a.length)

        {
            result[k] = a[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        while(j<b.length)

        {
            result[k] = b[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }

        while(l<c.length)
        {
            result[k]=c[l];
            l++;
            k++;
        }

        return result;

    }

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class MergeSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader R = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int arraySize = Integer.parseInt(R.readLine());
        int[] inputArray = new int[arraySize];
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
            inputArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(R.readLine());
        }
        mergeSort(inputArray);
        
        for (int j = 0; j < inputArray.length; j++) {
            System.out.println(inputArray[j]);
        }

    }
    
    static void mergeSort(int[] A) {
        if (A.length > 1) {
            int q = A.length/2;
            
//changed range of leftArray from 0-to-q to 0-to-(q-1),how would you edit Arrays.copyOfRange to manually make the same function without using any packages?
            *int[] leftArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(A, 0, q-1);
//changed range of rightArray from q-to-A.length to q-to-(A.length-1)

            int[] rightArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(A,q,A.length-1);*
            
            mergeSort(leftArray);
            mergeSort(rightArray);
            
            merge(A,leftArray,rightArray);
        }
    }
    
    static void merge(int[] a, int[] l, int[] r) {
        int totElem = l.length + r.length;
        //int[] a = new int[totElem];
        int i,li,ri;
        i = li = ri = 0;
        while ( i < totElem) {
            if ((li < l.length) && (ri<r.length)) {
                if (l[li] < r[ri]) {
                    a[i] = l[li];
                    i++;
                    li++;
                }
                else {
                    a[i] = r[ri];
                    i++;
                    ri++;
                }
            }
            else {
                if (li >= l.length) {
                    while (ri < r.length) {
                        a[i] = r[ri];
                        i++;
                        ri++;
                    }
                }
                if (ri >= r.length) {
                    while (li < l.length) {
                        a[i] = l[li];
                        li++;
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //return a;
        
    }
````

}

Answer (score 0):

This method not so fast as `Arrays.copyOfRange` and it not covers all cases, such as negative indexes, it is necessary to check also for size

```
private static int[] copyArray(int[] original, int from, int to) {
  int [] res = new int[to-from];
  for (int i = from; i< to; i++) {
    res[i - from] = original[i];
  }
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Top down merge sort with for loop for a one time array copy and alternating parameters to change direction of merge with each level of recursion. MergeSort is entry function that allocates and copies to a second array. MergeSortR is recursive function. Merge is never called unless all 3 sub-arrays have at least one element. The nested if | else in Merge only require 2 compares to determine the smallest element, but uses duplicate code to handle the case where a[a2] is the smallest element. (With C|C++ goto's can be used to avoid duplicate code). `bb` is beginning index, `ee` is ending index.

```
    static void MergeSort(int[] a)
    {
        if(a.length < 2)                // if < 2 elements, nothing to sort
            return;
        int [] b = new int[a.length];   // b[] = a[] | int[]b = a.clone();
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            b[i] = a[i];
        MergeSortR(b, a, 0, a.length);  // sort b[] to a[]
    }

    static void MergeSortR(int[] b, int[] a, int bb, int ee)
    {
        if(ee - bb < 2)                 // if < 2 elements, nothing to sort
            return;
        if(ee - bb == 2){               // if 2 elements
            if(a[bb] > a[bb+1]){
                int t = a[bb];
                a[bb] = a[bb+1];
                a[bb+1] = t;
            }
            return;
        }
        int m1 = bb+(ee+0-bb)/3;        // split into 3 parts
        int m2 = m1+(ee+1-bb)/3;
        MergeSortR(a, b, bb, m1);       // sort a[] to b[]
        MergeSortR(a, b, m1, m2);
        MergeSortR(a, b, m2, ee);
        Merge(b, a, bb, m1, m2, ee);    // merge b[] to a[]
    }
    
    static void Merge(int[] a, int[] b, int bb, int m1, int m2, int ee)
    {
        int b0 = bb;                    // b[] index
        int a0 = bb;                    // a[] indexes
        int a1 = m1;
        int a2 = m2;
        while(true){                    // 3 way merge
            if(a[a0] <= a[a1]){
                if(a[a0] <= a[a2]){
                    b[b0] = a[a0];      // a[a0] smallest
                    b0++;
                    a0++;
                    if(a0 < m1)         //  if not end of run
                        continue;       //   continue
                    a0 = a1;            //  else setup for 2 way merge
                    a1 = a2;
                    m1 = m2;
                    m2 = ee;
                    break;
                } else {
                    b[b0] = a[a2];      // a[a2] smallest
                    b0++;
                    a2++;
                    if(a2 < ee)         //  if not end of run
                        continue;       //   continue
                    break;              //  else setup for 2 way merge
                }
            } else {
                if(a[a1] <= a[a2]){
                    b[b0] = a[a1];     // a[a1] smallest
                    b0++;
                    a1++;
                    if(a1 < m2)         //  if not end of run
                        continue;       //   continue
                    a1 = a2;            //  else setup for 2 way merge
                    m2 = ee;
                    break;
                } else {
                    b[b0] = a[a2];      // a[a2] smallest
                    b0++;
                    a2++;
                    if(a2 < ee)         //  if not end of run
                        continue;       //   continue
                    break;              //  else setup for 2 way merge
                }
            }
        }    
        while(true){                    // 2 way merge
            if(a[a0] <= a[a1]){
                b[b0] = a[a0];
                b0++;
                a0++;
                if(a0 < m1)             //  if not end of run
                    continue;           //   continue
                a0 = a1;                //  else setup for copy
                m1 = m2;
                break;
            }else{
                b[b0] = a[a1];
                b0++;
                a1++;
                if(a1 < m2)             //  if not end of run
                    continue;           //   continue
                break;                  //  else setup for copy
            }
        }
        while(true){                    // copy rest of remaining run
            b[b0] = a[a0];
            b0++;
            a0++;
            if(a0 < m1)
                continue;
            break;
        }
    }
```